# Reloading/Refreshing Fragments in ViewPager/Tab implementation on a non-visible cached Fragment with custom Adapter

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin, android-viewpager

Im using tab layout (with **ViewPager,** it's Adapter is an extension of **FragmentStatePagerAdapter** and **TabLayout**) and im trying to refresh a listview on tab2 when i click on a button on tab1.
Im doing this job from the activity that holds the viewpager for now because i dont know any other way to do it.
The way i refresh it is to:

1. Monitor **OnTabSelected** of ViewPager
2. When tab2 become Visible, refresh the ListView with something like this:

   ```
   View _list = Activity.FindViewById(Resource.Id.MessagesListView);
   var _adapter = new MessagesAdapter(Activity, null);
   _adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
   _adapter = new MessagesAdapter(Activity, _reviewList);
   var _listview= (ListView)_list;
   _listview.Adapter = _adapter;
   _adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
   ```

As you might understand from the code, my problem is that the ListView doesnt replace its items, it only adds them in top of the others, how i can clear the listview?

I have also try with no luck with **.RemoveViews(0, test.ChildCount);**
My listview adapter is a simple extension of the BaseAdapter.

Also if you have another better way of Refreshing **ListView** or **Fragment** im open to suggestions

**EDIT:**

My final Adapter that works pretty well, if anyone has more suggestions to make it even better please make a comment

```
using Android.Support.V4.App;
using Android.Util;
using Java.Lang;

using Fragment = Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment;

namespace StaffPro
{
    public class TabsFragmentPagerAdapter : FragmentStatePagerAdapter
    {
        private readonly Fragment[] fragments;

        private readonly ICharSequence[] titles;

        SparseArray<Fragment> registeredFragments = new SparseArray<Fragment>();

        public TabsFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Fragment[] fragments, ICharSequence[] titles) : base(fm)
        {
            this.fragments = fragments;
            this.titles = titles;
        }
        public override int Count
        {
            get
            {
                return fragments.Length;
            }
        }

        public override Fragment GetItem(int position)
        {
            return fragments[position];
        }

        public override ICharSequence GetPageTitleFormatted(int position)
        {
            return titles[position];
        }
        public override void DestroyItem(Android.Views.View container, int position, Java.Lang.Object objectValue)
        {

            registeredFragments.Remove(position);
            base.DestroyItem(container, position, objectValue);
        }
        public override Java.Lang.Object InstantiateItem(Android.Views.ViewGroup container, int position)
        {
            Fragment fragment = (Fragment)base.InstantiateItem(container, position);
            registeredFragments.Put(position, fragment);
            return fragment;
        }
        public Fragment GetRegisteredFragment(int position)
        {
            return registeredFragments.Get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call a refresh directly within that fragment from the parent activity.

You'll need to implement on your ViewPager Adaptor a way for returning the fragment, so something like this:

```
    public override void DestroyItem(View container, int position, Object @object)
    {
        registeredFragments.Remove(position);
        base.DestroyItem(container, position, @object);
    }

    public override Object InstantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)
    {
        Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment fragment = (Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment)base.InstantiateItem(container, position);
        registeredFragments.Put(position, fragment);
        return fragment;
    }

    public Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment GetRegisteredFragment(int position)
    {
        return registeredFragments.Get(position);
    }
```

Then in your main activity:

```
    public void UpdateFragment()
    {
        var activeFragment = _Adaptor.GetRegisteredFragment(1); // where in the viewpager the fragment is
        ((YourFragment)activeFragment).MethodOnFragment();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i will try it ASAP, on the getregisteredfragment what is the position? the initial position that viewpager has load the fragments (in the line of the tabs for example,1 fragment 1tab, 2 fragment 2 tab etc) or its the position of the cached fragments?

Comment: @CDrosos So registered fragment should be of type SparseArray (SparseArray<Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment> registeredFragments = new SparseArray<Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment>();)  The position is where in the viewpager the fragment is registered. The InstantiateItem Puts the fragments position into this array when its Instantiated. So if you have a Viewpager with 4 pages and the you're on page 0 and the fragment is on page 4 the position is 3

Comment: Hello again, do you have in your mind a way for the fragment to display a spinning progress bar while its loading, when we change a tab? Like in Facebook's messenger, thanks